# Share a project that requires data persistence [Databases]

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I would like to share an application I created with java that has GUI. Imagine a contacts list, the user adds contacts and removes them.

I'm pretty new with databases but I know how to use them locally. I have created a Postgresql Database with proper tables that would contain the data written in the fields of the GUI. Everything works just fine locally on my computer.

I connected my Database with my java code.

My question is, if I would share that application with friends what should I do? Maybe my friend does not have installed a database system (e.g. Postgresql) on his computer, and in that case the application won't create the database correctly.

Is there a precise thing to do once you want to share a Database based app? I'm very new in sharing software. I would like to be more into that, any advice? Thank you.

Comment: Do all the application instances need to share just one database, or should every instance use its own?

Comment: I could be interested in both things, what would be the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to have a single database instance available for all users, then you need to have a computer that will run PostgreSQL server 24/7. All clients should connect to it over the internet (or local network).
2. If you want every user to have his own database instance on each computer, then what you need is basically called "embedded database". As you have already noticed, PostgreSQL requires additional stuff to be installed together with a copy of your software, so it's hard to distribute it. Moreover, it's not intended to be used this way as this is a server database. Usually **SQLite** is used in such cases instead.

Comment: So what I get from this answer is that each user has to download their own copy of the database system I used to program the application, is that wrong? So I have to let them install Postgre or SQLite or MySql.

Comment: SQLite is embedded into the application, so there is nothing to download and install in this case. Just take a look on SQLite, it has the same SQL syntax and is even easier to use (database is just a single file).

Answer (score 1):

You could use your database creation script and set a java method which execute that when you first time launch the application (if db already exists method does nothing). 
You should create also a configuration file where the user can set his database parameters and where you can read parameters to accede db and execute script.

Comment: got it, what about the version of the database system they have on their computer? should I force them installing a database system? with "database system" I mean Postgresql, MySql and so on..